# Passing Type to Method (w/o Generic) (C# Syntax)

Tags: c#, generics, methods

I've been looking for a way to create a temporary variable in the construction of a database manager.

```
public void Read(string name, string info, Type type){
    // blah temp = "Create temporary variable of type above"
    database.retrieve(name, info, out temp);
    Debug.Log (temp.ToString());
}
```

I tried passing Generics, but JSON doesn't like methods with Generics.  I feel like I'm on the verge of figuring it out with `typeof`, but I can't seem to find the syntax.

Edit: The temporary variable contains an overriden `ToString()`, so I can't simply `out` to and `Object`.

Comment: What is the declaration of `database.retrieve`?

Comment: `public bool retrieve<TKey, TValue>(string tableName, TKey key, out TValue value)`

Comment: A generic method should work, then.

Comment: `JsonTypeCoercionException: Interfaces, Abstract classes, and unsupported ValueTypes cannot be deserialized. (System.Type)`
Generics are abstract.

Comment: As is `var`.  Hence, the need to pass a specific type to be created to be `out` to.

Answer (score 3):

If `database.retrieve` is a generic method, the best option would be to make the method itself generic:

```
public void Read<T>(string name, string info)
{
     T temp;
     database.retrieve(name, info, out temp);
     // ...
}
```

Since it's an `out` parameter, you don't actually need to instantiate a temporary.  If it's non-generic, and takes `object`, just use object:

```
public void Read(string name, string info, Type type)
{
     object temp;
     database.retrieve(name, info, out temp);
     // ...
}
```

Comment: Then the second example does not need the generic type (and even the `Type` parmeter), right?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was saying that I had tried to make Read() pass a generic, and JSON didn't like it. So I had to find a different route.
Turns out my issue isn't solved.  I have overriden ToString() in the types I'm trying to pass to the Read(), so `Debug.Log()` doesn't return the proper string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. But this example assumes that your type has parameterless constructor. If you use .NET < 4.0 change `dynamic` to `Object`.

```
    public void Read(string name, string info, Type type)
    {
        ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes);
        if (ctor != null)
        {
            dynamic temp = ctor.Invoke(null);
            database.retrieve(name, info, out temp);
            Debug.Log(temp.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but Unity seems to hate that.  'Internal Compiler Error' :/